# How to specify data security constraints in REST APIs?

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing a REST API and I'm a big defender of keeping my URL simple, avoiding more than two nested resources.

However, I've been having second thoughts because of data security restrictions that apply to my APIs, that have been trying to force me to nest more resources. I'll try to provide examples to be more specific, as I don't know the correct naming for this situation.

Consider a simple example where I want to get a given contact restriction for a customer, like during what period my customer accepts to be bothered with a phone call:

So, I believe it's simpler to have this:

```
 - GET /customers/12345
 - GET /customers/12345/contacts
 - GET /contacts/9999
 - GET /contacts/9999/restrictions
 - GET /restrictions/1
```

than this:

```
 - GET /customers/12345
 - GET /customers/12345/contacts
 - GET /customers/12345/contacts/9999
 - GET /customers/12345/contacts/9999/restrictions
 - GET /customers/12345/contacts/9999/restrictions/1
```

Note: If there are more related resources, who knows where this will go...

The first case is my favourite because since all resources MUST have a unique identifier, as soon I have its unique identifier I should be able to get the resource instance directly: `GET /restrictions/1`

The data security restriction in place in my company states that not everyone can see every customers' info (eg: only some managers can access private equity customers). So, to guarantee that, the architects are telling me I should use `/customers/12345/contacts/9999/restrictions/1` or `/customers/12345/contact-restrictions/1` so that our data access validator in our platform has the customerId to check if the caller has access to it.

I understand the requirement and I see its value. However, I think that this kind of custom security informatio, because that's what I believe to be, should be in a custom header.

So, I believe I should stick to `GET /restriction/1` with a custom header "customerId" with the value 12345.
This custom header would only be needed for the apis that have this requirement.

Besides the simpler URL, another advantage of the header, is that if an API didn't start with that security requirement and suddenly needs to comply to it, we could simply require the header to be passed, instead of redefining paths.

I hope I made it clear for you and I'll be looking to learn more about great API design techniques.

Thank you all that reached the end of my post :)

Comment: I agree with your approach, security shouldn't make you compromise the integrity of your resource URI. I've no idea how a Restriction links to a Customer, but if you need to supply the Customer ID for verification then you could either pass it as a header or as a query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you are fighting over URI design, and REST doesn't actually offer guidance there.

REST, and REST clients, don't distinguish between your "simpler" design and the nested version.  A URI is just an opaque sequence of bytes with some little domain agnostic semantics.

```
/4290c3b2-134e-4647-867a-214d0c866f29
```

Is a perfectly "RESTFUL" URI.  See Stefan Tilkov, [REST: I don't Think it Means What You Think it Does.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM)

Fundamentally, REST servers are document stores.  You provide a key (the URI) and the server provides the document.  Or you provide a key, and the server modifies the document.

How this is *implemented* is completely at the discretion of the server.  It could be that `/4290c3b2-134e-4647-867a-214d0c866f29` is used to look up the tuple `(12345, 9999, 1)`, and then the server checks to see if the credentials described in the request header have permission to access that information, and if so the appropriate representation of the resource corresponding to that tuple is returned.

From the client's perspective, it's all the same thing: I provide an opaque identifier in a standard way, and credentials in a standard way, and I get access to the resource or I don't.

> the architects are telling me I should use /customers/12345/contacts/9999/restrictions/1 or /customers/12345/contact-restrictions/1 so that our data access validator in our platform has the customerId to check if the caller has access to it.
>
> I understand the requirement and I see its value. However, I think that this kind of custom security information, because that's what I believe to be, should be in a custom header.

There's nothing in REST to back you up.  In fact, the notion of introducing a custom header is something of a down check, because your customer header is not something that a *generic* component is going to know about.

When you need a new header, the "REST" way to go about it is to introduce a new standard.  See [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5) for an example.

Fielding, [writing in 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742)

> Every protocol, every media type definition, every URI scheme, and every link relationship type constitutes prior knowledge that the client must know (or learn) in order to make use of that knowledge. REST doesn’t eliminate the need for a clue. What REST does is concentrate that need for prior knowledge into readily standardizable forms.

The architects have a good point - encoding into the uri the hints that make it easier/cheaper/more-reliable to use *your* data access validator is *exactly* the sort of thing that allowing the servers to control their own URI namespace is supposed to afford.

The reason that this works, in REST, is that clients don't depend on URI for *semantics*; instead, they rely on the definitions of the relations that are encoded into the links (or otherwise expressed by the definition of the media type itself).

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm trying to have a consistent API inside the company, and more importantly, I want an API that's easy to understand by the human developer, so that he/she doesn't need to contact the team. The developer portal, with the attribute and verbs meaning is, for me, as important as the URIs in term of making the API understandable.

Another thing,I want the API to be the same for internal and external usage. External clients won't even know the Ids the data access validator needs. In my vision,that will be transparent and coded inside the jwt token we'll give them.(cont)

Comment: (cont) If I have that information in the URI, I'll have to have different endpoints for internal/external exposure, and that was something I was trying to avoid, to reduce the time to market of any API my board decides to expose.